# Socket buffer size for small messages

Tags: java, sockets, buffer

I am writing simple MMO game (Just learning sockets etc.), and now I have a question. If my messages are usually really really small (5-20 bytes), should I use small buffer size for my socket like 32Bytes, or stay with buffer size like 512 bytes (which will be not filled in 99% messages).

Comment: What problem you try to solve?

Comment: I don't want to create app that is taking all network trafic with 5 players..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your buffer is large enough to accommodate the size of your data, then you will avoid the slow process of filling up the buffer again between every reading operation, and that's what matters. I guess, if you have a decent server there's no harm in leaving the default value (As the application evolves, you might need that extra space down the line anyway).

Also, why reinventing the wheel? How about using JMS or XMPP, there are more interesting challenges in an MMO game than worrying about the size of your buffers :)